# QML/MouseArea: onEntered not triggered when mouse pressed on another mouse area

Tags: qt, qml

I need to detect a selection range with MouseAreas. So I want to detect a mousePressed on any object, before the release I need to detect onEntered on any other object and then mouseRelease on anyObject
I'm focusing on detecting enter events on an item after pressing on another item.
A simplification of my objects:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle  {
    property color color: "red"
    property string name: "rect1"
    property Item mousePressedObserver
    width: 100
    height: 20
    border.color: ma.visible ? color: "grey"
    border.width: 1
    MouseArea {
        id: ma
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        preventStealing: false
        propagateComposedEvents: true

        drag.target: undefined
        onPressed: {
            if(mousePressedObserver) mousePressedObserver.onPressed()
            mouse.accepted = true
        }
        onPositionChanged: mouse.accepted = true
        onReleased: if(mousePressedObserver) mousePressedObserver.onReleased()
        onEntered: {border.width= 2; console.log(name + " entered")}
        onExited: {border.width= 1; console.log(name + " exited"); hoverEnabled= false}
        onContainsMouseChanged: console.log(name + " containsMouse: " + containsMouse)
    }
}
```

A simplification of my view:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    MouseArea {
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onPressed: indicator.onPressed()
        onReleased: indicator.onReleased()
        ColumnLayout {
            CustomRect {mousePressedObserver: indicator}
            CustomRect { name: "rect2"; color: "blue"; mousePressedObserver: indicator}
            CustomRect { name: "rect3"; color: "green"; mousePressedObserver: indicator}
            MouseStatusIndicator { id: indicator}
        }
    }
}
```

If I press on the first rect, and without releasing, mouve to the second rect, the onEntered handler is called only after releasing the mouse. If i don't press the mouse, enter is detected "real-time". Is it possible to detect the enter event even if mousse is pressed?